# Displaying frames in a form of video on google colab

Tags: opencv, google-colaboratory, video-processing

I am a trying video processing on google colab. My code read the video and break it into frames and after the processing on the frame I want to display the video as frames are processed. Like what  `cv2.imshow`  does (on local computer).  But  `cv2.imshow`  gives error in colab so as it suggested I used  `cv2_imshow`  using   `from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow` . It is displaying the frames but in an column(like separate images) but replacing the previous displayed. Here is my colab link: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1RUOGahcGngTWG9nBoisrsPzCLQ1Jq88v?usp=sharing
You can  see the output at the end of the page where multiple images are.
Any help is really appreciated :)

Comment: This is not clear to understand the problem -> *"It is displaying the frames but in an column(like separate images)"*

Comment: Here is my colab link 
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1RUOGahcGngTWG9nBoisrsPzCLQ1Jq88v?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
from IPython.display import clear_output
from time import sleep

clear_output()
cv2_imshow(img)
sleep(0.1)
```

it's far from perfect (since there are some frame drops for some reason), but that's the closest thing I could find.